# Laravel: Using an instance created in one function within another?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a `User` controller where set Data is run at a certain point and `UserProduct`'s create method is used to create a `UserProduct`.  I want to use the `UserProduct` in a different function.  Would the best way to do so just query the latest record of `UserProduct` and set it to a variable?

```
use App\Models\UserProduct;

public function setData($data) {
    // other logic
    UserProduct::create([
       'id' => $data->id
    ]);

}

public function logInfo() {
   
    $myVar = UserProduct::latest()->first();
 
    //use myVar

}
```

Comment: That would work. But it's not guaranteed that it will get you the record that is saved via setData function, because maybe another record has been inserted in between.

Comment: Can you pass the ```$data``` object to ```logInfo()```? The you could use ```UserProduct::where('id', $data->id)->latest()->get()```.